# How do I make a bone synchronize another bone's movement?

Tags: animation, armature, bones

[image: Armature]

I have an armature with a simple IK on both hands and would like them to move together at the same time in a symmetrical fashion. Let's say I wanna make a clapping animation, how do you make both hands move at the same time toward each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the left IK controller is supposed to control the right IK controller, give your right IK controller the bone constraints *Copy Location* and *Copy Rotation* with these settings (enable *Invert* X for the *Copy Location* and *Invert* Y and Z for *Copy Rotation*, and choose *Local Space/Local Space* for both):

[image]

Then here is what happens when you move the left IK controller:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Mirroring]

**Another way I found out to synchronize changes to a matching bone is by enabling the 'X', on the top right corner of the viewport.**